# Pandas: How do I assign multiple values based on different combinations of column content?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column with a numerical value based on the following conditions:

a. if color=blue & pet=dog, points=10

b. if color=blue & pet=cat, points=8

c. if pet=snake & gender=female, points=7

d. if pet=mouse & gender=male, points = 6

All rows must meet one of those conditions. The rows will never meet 2 or none of the conditions.

```
    color     pet       gender
0   blue      dog       male
1   blue      cat       male
2   orange    snake     female
3   green     mouse     male
```

I would like the end result to be as follows:

```
    color     pet       gender     points
0   blue      dog       male       10
1   blue      cat       male       8
2   orange    snake     female     7
3   green     mouse     male       6
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing a very long one-liner, I think 4 separate assignments which are masked using `loc` would be more readable:

```
In [4]:
df.loc[(df['color']=='blue') & (df['pet']=='dog'), 'points'] = 10
df.loc[(df['color']=='blue') & (df['pet']=='cat'), 'points'] = 8
df.loc[(df['pet']=='snake') & (df['gender']=='female'), 'points'] = 7    
df.loc[(df['pet']=='mouse') & (df['gender']=='male'), 'points'] = 6
df

Out[4]:

    color    pet  gender  points
0    blue    dog    male      10
1    blue    cat    male       8
2  orange  snake  female       7
3   green  mouse    male       6
```

It would be possible to rewrite the above into a multi-nested `np.where` statement but I find that once you get above 3 conditions it becomes difficult to read and there isn't much to gain performance wise against separate `loc` statements